# Split every second occurrence of delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, split

I am trying to use awk to split a file every second occurrence of a delimiter, but I always end up with an empty file at the beginning and I can't understand why.

The data I need to break down in multiple files has a format similar to this:

```
----------
aaa
bbb
----------
ccc
ddd
----------
eee
fff
----------
ggg
```

The first resulting file should contain:

```
----------
aaa
bbb
----------
ccc
ddd
```

The delimiter is always the same (10 times a 'minus' sign).
I am trying to do it like this for now:

```
awk -v RS='[-]{10}' '{i++} {file = sprintf("temp-%s", int(i/2)); print >> file;}'
```

The first file I get however (temp-0) always includes an empty line and nothing else.
Also, the source file does not start with an empty line, nor it has any in its content (they have been removed previously).

Can anybody please help?

Comment: what would be the first field value if you split `a,b,c` with `,` as separator? it will be `a` ... how about `,b,c`? first field will be empty... same concept with record separator.. you get empty file because there is nothing before the first match

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't play with `RS` for this problem. You can count the `---------` to decide if you have to increment the file index. Give this line a try:

```
awk '/^--*$/{c++;f+=c%2?1:0}{print > "temp-"f}' file
```

Note that the above line gives you the idea of how to process the line and file index. If your file is huge, you need `close()` the file and using `>>` to redirect again, otherwise you will get errors like `too many opened files`.